# table-cell Div Expanding Beyond Size of Content Inside

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to create a representation of a Sudoku puzzle in React.  I am using divs with display modes of table, table-row, and table-cell with a readonly input box inside to accomplish this.  However, my table to does not look as intended as it has weird gaps above the input boxes.  If I make the input box >= 30x30 it looks fine though.

```
interface HistCellProps {
  value: number;
}

function HistCell({value}: HistCellProps ) {
  return (
    //<div className='test'></div>
    <input value={value} className='histCellInput' readOnly />
  );
}

interface HistGridProps {
  grid: number[][];
}

function HistGrid({grid}: HistGridProps) {
  return (
    <div className='histGrid'>
      {grid.map((row: number[], rowIndex: number) =>
        <div key={rowIndex} className={(rowIndex + 1) % 3 == 0 ? 'bHistRowBorder' : 'nHistRowBorder'}>
          {row.map((value: number, colIndex: number) =>
            <div key={colIndex} className={(colIndex + 1) % 3 == 0 ? 'rHistBorder' : 'nHistBorder'}>
              <HistCell value={value} />
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
.histGrid {
  display: table;
  border: solid 2px black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.nHistRowBorder {
  display: table-row;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.bHistRowBorder {
  display: table-row;
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-bottom: solid 2px black;
}

.nHistBorder {
  display: table-cell;
  border: solid 2px black;
}

.rHistBorder {
  display: table-cell;
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-right: solid 2px black;
}

.histCellInput {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 7.5px;
  color: black;
  background-color: azure;
  border: 0px solid black;
}
```

[image]